# Prove a function is convex and relevant limits.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly increasing continuous function with $f(0)>0$. Set $c=f(1)$ and $g(x)=\int _0 ^1 (f(t))^x dt$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove the following:

A) $g(x)$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$

B) $$\lim _{n \to \infty}g(n)^{1/n}=c$$
C) $$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac {g(n)}{c^n}=0$$
D) $$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac {g(n+1)}{g(n)}=c$$
For A, I know that I can compute the second derivative and show that it is positive, and thus $g(x)$ is convex. For parts B through D, I have no clue where to start. Any help is greatly appreciated, and a full solution to B in particular would be welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Part $B)$, we proceed as follows.  First, write $g^{1/n}(n)$ as

$$g^{1/n}(n)=\left(\int_0^1 f^n(t)\,dt\right)^{1/n}=c\left(\int_0^1 \left(\frac{f(t)}{c}\right)^n\,dt\right)^{1/n}\tag 1$$

Let $h(t)=f(t)/c$.  Then, $h(t)$ is continuous and increasing on $[0,1]$.  Furthermore $0<h(t)\le 1$.  Note that we can write for any $0<\epsilon<1$

$$\int_0^1 h^n(t)\,dt=\int_0^{1-\epsilon} h^n(t)\,dt+\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 h^n(t)\,dt$$

from which we can deduce the estimates

$$\epsilon^{1/n} h(1-\epsilon)\le \left(\int_0^1h^n(t)\,dt\right)^{1/n}\le 1$$

Letting $n\to \infty$, we find that for all $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ we have

$$h(1-\epsilon)\le \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\int_0^1h^n(t)\,dt\right)^{1/n}\le 1 \tag 2$$

Since $(2)$ is true for all $\epsilon\in (0,1)$, then given that $h(t)$ is continuous and increasing with $h(1)=1$, we find that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\int_0^1h^n(t)\,dt\right)^{1/n}=1 \tag 3$$

Putting $(3)$ together with $(1)$ yields the coveted limit

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\int_0^1 f^n(t)\,dt\right)^{1/n}=c$$

Comment: I understand this process and was able to do something similar for part D. I am still struggling with part C, though.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: No, I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Well, let's try another approach then.  Let $h=f/c$.  Then, $$\frac{g(n)}{c^n}=\int_0^1 h^n(t)\,dt=\int_0^{r} h^n(t)\,dt+\int_{r}^1 h^n(t)\,dt \le r h^n(r)+(1-r)$$For fixed $r$, let $n\to \infty$.  Then we see that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{g(n)}{c^n}\le (1-r)$.  As this holds for all $r\in (0,1)$, we deuce the announced result.

Answer (score 0):

(This answers B.) The expression 
$$M(p)= \left( \int _0 ^1 [f(x)]^p dx \right)^{1/p}$$
is the generalised mean (or power mean with exponent $p$) of the function $f(x)$. The generalised power inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) states that $M_p \le M_q$ for $p \le q$ and moreover
$$\lim_{p \uparrow \infty} M_p = M_{\infty} = \max f(x)$$

In your problem, since $f(x)$ is increasing, $\max f(x) = f(1) = c$, yielding
$$\lim _{n \to \infty} g(n)^{1/n} = \lim _{n \to \infty} M (n)=c$$